# Model/Specification describing a key-value database

Tags: database-design, nosql, redis, data-modeling, key-value-store

I am looking for a formal/semi-formal way to describe the model of a database using a key-value approach (e.g. Redis).

I guess it all comes down to describing the naming scheme (what to expect for each key): is there any model that's good at doing that? Any example would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate what are you trying to do? The OP is a bit unclear

Comment: I would like to have a document describing the database structure, e.g. ER diagram but for key-value database. Mainly to communicate the structure to other members of the team.

Comment: Are you describing an EAV? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model